# Django vs Python2.7 unittest TestCase?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm building a Django app, and I'm trying to decide how to set up unit-tests for my code. Looking at Django documentation, I see that there are two options for unit-tests, Python2.7's built-in tests and Django's custom TestCase class. When trying to see which one to use, Django seemed to only list benefits for Python (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#which-should-i-use).

Which unit-test framework is preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use Django `TestCase`. It does everything that the python `unittest.TestCase` can do and more.

The python and Django `TestCase` classes are both for unit tests. The [*Which should I use*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#which-should-i-use) section that you link to is comparing *unit tests* with *doc tests*.

The Django `TestCase` is just an extension of the python `unittest.TestCase`. If you are using an earlier version of Python, then the Django `TestCase` allows you to use some neat features like `assertRaisesExp` which are only available in `unittest.TestCase` for python 2.7.

Since you are using Python 2.7, you don't need to use the Django `TestCase` for the Python 2.7 functionality, but there are still lots of extra features, for example [fixture loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#fixture-loading), which mean you should use the Django `TestCase`.

Comment: Django's `TestCase` just redistributes the latest `unittest` module to ensure all the features are available for older interpreters. It's something you'd probably want to do manually otherwise, if you wanted to ensure you can use `unittests` 2 and still maintain Python 2.5 compatibility, which is what somebody would expect. There are other things redistributed as well for Python 2.5 compatibility.