# Python unit testing without django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

How can I write unittests in Python (3.4), which are not dependent on any django stuff?

At first I thought Pycharm did somehow artifically add django dependencies to my unittests, but then I checked by just running

```
python <test containing file>
```

And I still get this weird django output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_pinyinTones2NumbersTransformer.py", line 2, in <module> from PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer import PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer
    File "/home/xiaolong/PycharmProjects/PinyinTransformer/pinyintransformer/PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer.py", line 1, in <module> from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes.generation import void_output
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Here is my source code of the test file:

```
import unittest
from PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer import PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer

class TestPinyinTones2NumbersTransformer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer = PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer()

    def test_setText (self):
        self.fail()

    def test_transform (self):
        self.fail()

    def test_getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable (self):
        self.assertEquals(self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer.getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable("ne"), 0)
        self.assertEquals(self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer.getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable("ān"), 1)
        self.assertEquals(self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer.getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable("péng"), 2)
        self.assertEquals(self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer.getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable("nǐ"), 3)
        self.assertEquals(self.pinyin_tones_2_numbers_transformer.getToneNumberOfTonedSyllable("jiào"), 4)
```

My project has absolutely nothing to do with django. I've tried a django tutorial before, but that had nothing to do with what I am doing now. Also I deleted django after seeing this message, because I thought maybe the Python interpreter is confused with django also having a module called unittest, but that didn't fix the issue.

I found this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345948/django-vs-python2-7-unittest-testcase
```

But first of all: I am using Python 3.4 and I don't care about backwards compatibility of my tests. No one else will probably see or maybe even use my programm anyways. It's just a sort of exercise for myself, to get more used to writing tests.

All I want to do is write simple tests for the methods in my classes, without any django bonus super mega ... Also I am quite sure that default unittests of Python itself are more than enough for my little project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit tests are subclassing `unittest.TestCase`, so they are not using any Django stuff.

The traceback is telling you that `PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer` imports `void_output` from `django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes.generation`. Therefore, you require `django` to be installed to run your test unless you change `PinyinTones2NumbersTransformer`.

Comment: Right now I feel quite stupid. Pycharm for some unthinkable reason put in a django import into the file, but I couldn't see that, because somehow I was able to open the same file twice in Pycharm and I only saw the version without any django import. But why??? did it insert a django import?! -.-
Thanks anyways, you solved the riddle.